# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Dort' of undefined

Tags: javascript

im trying to make a basic quiz with JS but there is a problem that i couldn't figure out. Everything seems true but im getting the error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Dort' of undefined". 
Here's my code:

```js
  var sorular = [
      ["Bir insanın kaç bacağı vardır?", "Ikı"]
      ["Bir insanın kaç gözü vardır?", "Ikı"]
      ["Ikiyi kendisi ile çarparsak kaç eder?", "Dort"]
    ];
    
    var dogruCevap 
    var yanlisCevap
    
    var soru1 = prompt(sorular[0][0]);
    if (soru1 == sorular[0][1]) {
      console.log("doğru")
    }
```

Comment: See [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) on how to get better results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sorular` array not a valid one.Missing with `,` to separate the arguments with in array

```js
var sorular = [
  ["Bir insanın kaç bacağı vardır?", "Ikı"], // missing the `,` separator  
  ["Bir insanın kaç gözü vardır?", "Ikı"], //missing the `,` separator
  ["Ikiyi kendisi ile çarparsak kaç eder?", "Dort"]
];

var dogruCevap
var yanlisCevap

var soru1 = prompt(sorular[0][0]);
if (soru1 == sorular[0][1]) {
  console.log("doğru")
}
```

Comment: Can you point out more, i dont see the diffenrence?

Oh, i saw it now. Thank you. :)

Comment: see the `,` in`sorular` array `[[], [], []]` .check my upadted answer

Comment: Welcome. if you satisfied with my answer.Mark it as an answer its helpful for the future visitors